# Creating directories from a list

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a list (list.txt)

```
E001    Apples    Good stuff
E002    Pears    Nicely done
E091    Grapes    Bleah
```

I wanted to create directories using the first column so I tried

```
#!/bin/sh
for num in $(seq 1 3) #Because the list is long
do
cat list.txt | cut -f1 | awk 'NR==$num{print}' > idx.tmp
idx=$(idx.tmp)
mkdir $idx
rm idx.tmp
done
```

Not only is this conceivably bulky, it doesn't work - even though `cat list.txt | cut -f1 | awk 'NR==1 {print}'` gives me the name of the individual directory I want (i.e. E001)

Ideally I wish to obtain a bunch of empty folders created within the folder which the script ran (does that sound right?) named using the first column of each row in `list.txt`.

Comment: I tried `idx=$(cat list.txt | cut -f1 | awk 'NR==$num{print}') ` but got Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done"), that's why I changed to idx=$(idx.tmp).  Similarly `idx=$(cat idx.tmp)` gives the same error :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple loop suffices:

```
while read dirname others; do
    mkdir "$dirname"
done < list.txt
```

This reads a line at a time from the file, setting the value of `dirname` to the first field and `others` to the remaining portion for each line, and runs `mkdir` with the given directory name.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 file | xargs echo mkdir
```

or

```
awk '{print $1}' file | xargs echo mkdir
```

If everything looks okay remove `echo`.

Comment: I'm sorry but for some reason this didn't work for me. @chepner's loop did though..

Comment: Perhaps the `-p` option was needed; otherwise some `mkdir` commands will fail, if the respective parent directories do not exist.

Comment: @Turtle: I've fixed a big bug in my version with awk.